# At the end of my rope - Virtualbox not booting my Windows 10 VHD

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, vhd

I am interested in moving from Windows to Linux, but I have some applications on Windows that I still use (university requires it) and thus I would like to build a Windows 10 virtual machine.

I used disk2vhd to convert my current Windows 10 into a `.vhd` file, and then I ran it on Virtualbox and selected the existing hard disk. However, no matter what I tweaked, the system said

> FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted.

I've read the very instructional user manual for Virtualbox, but unfortunately it didn't provide answers. I followed all the instructions on this and other websites that solved the same problem on other machines, like simply configuring the Controller IDE (my controller IDE doesn't even show under Storage, and when I add it manually and want to choose a file, the `.vhd` is not available). So I am pretty confused.

Might there be something wrong with my laptop, or what am I missing?

Comment: Did your Windows 10 machine come with Windows 10?  If so, it is (very likely) OEM and cannot be moved. If you need Linux to be your host machine, consider getting a license for Windows 10 and install that as a fresh install in Virtual Box.  I have installed Windows 10 in VMware Workstation this way (Windows Insider)

Comment: While there might be a Windows licensing issue that might exist, it certainly isn’t the reason, the author is unable to do what they describe.  This is likely more of an issue with compatibility between the file being generated by the command and VirtualBox

Comment: To be very clear, I do not suggest licensing is the cause of the problem, just that (a) if you get there and cannot activate (licensing) then all is in vain and (b) I have done fresh installs of Windows 10 to avoid compatibility issues.